# laravel where criteria on related table without join?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

```
Users UserChallenges(user_id,challenge_id) Challenges(start,end)
```

I want to get all UserChallenges for a user within a given timerange:

```
$challengeIds = Challenge::where('start', '>=', $timestamp)
            ->where('end', '<=', $timestamp)->pluck('id');

UserChallenge::where('user_id', $userId)->whereIn('id', $challengeIds)->get();
```

I know that I could do it in one query using joins, but I would prefer a more eloquent like way using the relations that I have setup in the models. Is this somehow possible?

Comment: Not sure to understand 100% of what you want, but I think relationship and WhereHas() method could help https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `whereHas` method:

```
$users = User::where('id', $userId)
             ->whereHas('challenges', function ($q) use ($timestamp) {
                 $q->where('start', '>=', $timestamp)
                   ->where('end', '<=', $timestamp);
             })->get();
```

You will also have to define `belongsToMany` method in User model.